# count average number of increasing consecutive integers R with rle

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have two columns in my data frame, a left column that represents id, and a right column that has contains increasing integers, some that are consecutive, and some that are not.  There are no repeating integers.  My objective is to obtain the average number of consecutive integers per `id` 
For example:

Here is a fragment of my dataset

`station summary id`

```
> data
      id moment
4448   1  11725
4540   1  11726
5457   1  11739
5519   1  11740
11733  1  11861
11797  1  11862
12020  1  11865
12313  1  11869
14576  1  11914
23314  1  12088
166    2  11644
278    2  11646
339    2  11647
407    2  11648
476    2  11649
545    2  11650
673    2  11652
737    2  11653
982    2  11657
1035   2  11658
```

In the above sample  **id 1**  has the following number of consecutive integers in `moment` -   2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1  - so the average would be 1.428

**id 2**  has  the following number of consecutive integers in `moment` - 1, 5, 2, 2 - so the average would be 2.5

The real dataset has ~ 200 rows and 300 unique ids - I would like the average for each id.

I know that you have to use the rle() function somehow, and I am able to find the max number with the following code:

```
aggregate( data$moment, dat['id'], FUN= function(d) max( rle( diff(d) )$lengths ) )
```

How would one take the average ?

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), moment = c(11725L, 11726L, 
11739L, 11740L, 11861L, 11862L, 11865L, 11869L, 11914L, 12088L, 
11644L, 11646L, 11647L, 11648L, 11649L, 11650L, 11652L, 11653L, 
11657L, 11658L)), .Names = c("id", "moment"), row.names = c(4448L, 
4540L, 5457L, 5519L, 11733L, 11797L, 12020L, 12313L, 14576L, 
23314L, 166L, 278L, 339L, 407L, 476L, 545L, 673L, 737L, 982L, 
1035L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a nicer way, but...

```
aggregate(data$moment,list(data$id), function(x) mean(rle(diffinv(diff(x)!=1))$lengths))
#   Group.1        x
# 1       1 1.428571
# 2       2 2.500000
```

**Explanation**

We first take the difference. We then look for those number that are not consecutive (`diff(x)!=1`). We then take the inverse of the difference (`diffinv`) to go back to the original length. We now have a vector that increments when at non-consecutive numbers. Take `rle` of that, then the lenghts and finally apply `mean`, and you're done.

Edit1: Removed a step that was unnecessary.